# When I first enter an input (name), the message does not display the name. I have to press enter again for the message to display with the name

Tags: c#, events, delegates

```
using System;

public class NameChangeEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }

    public NameChangeEventArgs(string name)
    {
        this.Name = name;
    }
}

public class Dispatcher
{
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name; 
        }
        set
        {
            OnNameChange(_name);

            _name = value; 
        } 
    }

    public event EventHandler<NameChangeEventArgs> NameChange;

    protected virtual void OnNameChange(string name)
    {
        NameChange?.Invoke(this, new NameChangeEventArgs(name));
    }
}

public class Handler
{
    public void OnDispatcherNameChange(object Source, NameChangeEventArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Dispatcher's name changed to {0}", args.Name);
    } 
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
        var handler = new Handler();

        dispatcher.NameChange += handler.OnDispatcherNameChange;

        var name = "Sidd";
        dispatcher.Name = name;
    }
}
```

The purpose of my code is to change Dispatcher's name to the name passed to it, but whilst this is done, an event is raised to run a method in the Handler class to display the name to which the Dispatcher has been changed to.

The "OnDispatcherNameChange(object Source, NameChangeEventArgs args)" is called to display the message "Dispatcher's name changed to " in my dispatcher's setter.

However it outputs this instead...

```
Dispatcher's name changed to

Press any key to continue...
```

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's because you're raising the event before changing the property. 
The code that receives the event will read the old name and not notice the new one.

Try doing this instead:

```
set
{
    // First change the property
    _name = value; 

    // Then raise the event
    OnNameChange(_name);
}
```

Comment: Oh God what a dumb mistake. Thanks. I should've noticed that